# PHP form option selected

Tags: php, selection

I'm using the code below to auto fill the option values for a drop-down. I'm have trying getting it to have the number 30 selected. Right now it's displaying the number 30 twice out of sequence. how would I get that sequence to display 18-75 with 30 pre-selected.

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) 
echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 
echo '<option value=30 selected>30</option>';
?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a highly redundant question. Please educate yourself about the existing Q&A about that topic first and then pinpoint to a concrete issue. Using echo and sprintf() in one expression somehow shows that you have problems to grasp a general understanding. I would start with improving at that point otherwise you'll do more and more mistakes and you keep on constantly wondering.

Comment: @hakre question answered multiple times below, others understood

Comment: I wrote redundant. As it's a uber-duplicate, if you wanna ask such question, outline which part specific different to the many others existing materials yours contain. In that sense your question was totally not clear. It's not clear why you ask it as it has been already answered in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) 
{
  if($k!=30)
  {
   echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 
  }
  else
  {
   echo '<option selected="selected" value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 
  }
}   
?>
</select>
```

Comment: +1. little bit of explanation is also required.

Comment: lol thanks, sorry on mobile

Comment: Nope, the original `for` loop only runs the first line, since they are not grouped in `{ braces }`.

Comment: @icedwater oops yes you are right, that makes my explanation wrong

Comment: Well, I got your attention, didn't I? :P

Comment: @icedwater +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Use Below code

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) {
    $selected = '';
    if($k == 30){
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).' '.$selected.' >'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 

}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to check for the value in every iteration and echo if value is 30.

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++){
  $value = sprintf("%02d", $k) ; ?>
  <option value='<?php echo $value ; ?>' <?php echo ($value == 30) ? "selected" : "" ; ?>><?php echo $value ; ?></option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

30 is being displayed out of sequence because you didn't include the statements in a set of braces, so the `for` loop is only looping on the first line. 30 is then printed only after the entire loop is done, i.e. after `$k == 75`.

I would suggest defining a `$default` value should you have to change the number later:

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
    $default = 30;
    for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) {
        if ($k == $default) {
            echo '<option value=' . $default . 'selected>' . $default . '</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `30` option in each loop iteration  you have to put it in some condition

```
    <select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) {
if($k ==30)
{
 echo '<option selected="selected" value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 

}
else
{
  echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 
}  

} 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="age2" class="numb">
<?php 
for ($k = 18; $k <= 75; $k++) 
 echo '<option value='.sprintf("%02d", $k).  (if($k==30)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.sprintf("%02d", $k).'</option>'; 
 }
?>
</select>
```